# Accessing a standalone PHP file

Tags: php, drupal

How would you reference an actual file in a Drupal project?

I have a flash app that needs to talk to a php script, but I can't just say "http://{domain}/{filepath}/{file}" or even "http://{domain}/{file}" assuming there was some assumed pathing structure.

To be more specific, the file lives in /sites/all/flash/postit.php. How would Drupal tie it's database driven content to an actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you postit.php use additional includes, that have next structure:

```
FOLDER1/someincludefile.php
someincludefile.php
postit.php
```

and use relative path for including, it will raise error that files doesn't found, so you can include in next manner:

```
  $cwd = getcwd(); // current dir. usually where index.php running.
  $file = base_path() ."/sites/all/flash/postit.php"; // path to our script
  $dir = dirname($file);
  chdir($dir); // changing to file folder.
  require_once('postit.php'); 
  // Run your code
  ..

  chdir($cwd); // return to own dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference it with a PHP include such as

`include "/sites/all/flash/postit.php";`

If you try to include it with http://domain.com/postit.php the webserver will process the PHP file and all you'll get is the HTML output.